# SAPUI5 List Item Template same value repeated

Tags: sapui5

I built an oData service that delivers two or more records from a database table.
When testing it with /IWFND/GW_CLIENT it works great and I get the information I need. 
But when I bind it to a StandardList item which is defined as template, then I only get two List Items (which is correct because the oData Service delivers two records) but they have the same value which is not correct because the value should be different. 
I'll add some screenshots for better understanding. 
Maybe someone can tell me why the list is not display the correct items.

Thanks

Started App view
[image: Started App view]

GW-Client result
[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58959791/5846045. Your key predicates are not unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have oData entity keys which have same values (Mandt='200',Kunnr='10') for both the records. This is the reason for the repeated values. You should have unique key values such that each entry is uniquely identifiable.

To fix this, you should keep properties which have unique values as keys or add multiple properties as keys in your gateway service implementation.